# I am trying to debug LWC in chrome dev console, but I can't. I am a newbie, guidance please

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I am working on wire service, I get the output on UI (salesforce UI), I want to be able to see the response data in the dev console so that I manipulate the data on template.

Usualy we should be able to see the component in the console. I cannot see my component there. What settings do I enable

Comment: Have you looked in the correct javascript source path folder to find the compiled LWC code for your component in the browser inspector? When looking, are you sure your component has been loaded into the page (can you see it)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

please make sure that you have added console.log() wherever needed inside the component.
Wire service provisions data as an immutable stream of key value pairs, which you access as:

```
 @wire (accounts, {recordId:recordId})
    fetchAccount({error, data}){
        if(data){
          //HERE YOU RECIEVE THE DATA
            console.log(data);
        }else if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    };
```

That's a quick way. But if you want to go ahead for clean debugging, better to put breakpoints in the line and observe that for error in the output/dev console.

I can see wireDemoUserDetail.js in console, is that your component?"

Also, I would encourage you to go ahead and read the guidelines for asking a question, Phil knows it better than me. If possible, please provide a snippet of your code here using the editor instead of screenshots.

Comment: Dweepayan Sharma, no that is not my component. The picture above that is my component. Let me add console.log().

Comment: Hi can you check if you have 'hidden(eye icon)' checked in dev console? I will be helping you out in this, If needed, then you can share a snapshot of your entire code as well!

Comment: Please don't encourage use of screenshots to share code - it is unsearchable and also makes it much harder to suggest code changes.

Comment: Agreed, by snapshot I meant a glimpse of the entire code, maybe repos like git or fiddle...or a copy paste in code console.
You have raised an excellent point, no doubt.

Comment: It is working now guys. Thank you. console.log(data) worked.

Comment: Someone just downvoted this, without an explanation. I would be happy if somone could point out my mistake, it really helps me rectify myself.

Comment: probably because console.log is not the best option for debugging, breakpoints in the src code using the browsers dev tools is the recommended approach (debugging 101)